# Read a complete XML node with children and write into another XML file using VBS

Tags: xml, vbscript, xml-parsing

I receive 2 XML files from a third party service every day and I need to combine them using VBS as it is the only available technology on the server that consumes the XML. Each of the XML files has the same structure -

```
<section>
    <lot>
        <number>8</number>
        <identifier>au23-zx78a</identifier>
    </lot>
    <lot>
        <number>23</number>
        <identifier>au23-zx78a</identifier>
    </lot>
    ...and so on...
</section>
```

I need to take all of the lot nodes (including any and all children) from file 1 and insert them into file 2 before saving file 2 to be consumed by another service. Using VBS.

I have searched the web and I have found ways to get a node out using VBS but I am lost on getting the nodes into another file. I have written and scrapped 3 or 4 scripts today because I have not been able to get it right.

I know that the logic is this -

load file 1,
load file 2,
get the lot nodes from file 1,
loop through the lot nodes from file 1 and append them as children of the section node in file 2,
save file 2

Can anyone help me by pointing me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple way of doing it: load both xml files into [`MSXML2.DomDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms756987%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) objects, select all the `lot` nodes from the first document, clone them and insert them into the second document.

```vb
option explicit

' collect xml file paths from the command line
dim xmlpath1: xmlpath1 = WScript.Arguments(0)
dim xmlpath2: xmlpath2 = WScript.Arguments(1)

' open up the xml files, this might need some error handling
dim xmldoc1: set xmldoc1 = CreateObject("MSXML2.DomDocument")
xmldoc1.async = false
xmldoc1.load xmlpath1
xmldoc1.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
dim xmldoc2: set xmldoc2 = CreateObject("MSXML2.DomDocument")
xmldoc2.async = false
xmldoc2.load xmlpath2

' get a collection of lot nodes
dim lots: set lots = xmldoc1.selectNodes("/section/lot")
' loop through each lot, clone it and add it to the second document
dim lot
for each lot in lots
    dim l: set l = lot.cloneNode(true)
    xmldoc2.documentElement.appendChild l
next

' overwrite the second document
xmldoc2.save xmldoc2.url
```

The script (if called merge-xml.vbs) would be run from the command line

> cscript merge-xml.vbs xml1.xml xml2.xml

Comment: I will give this a shot this morning. Thanks for posting it!

Comment: I made some changes to fit the situation but this works perfectly! Thanks for sharing this. I had not thought about the cloning part and you really opened my eyes.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to provide vbscript example of how I read unlimited XML files clone the contents and create a new XML file and then reads it into to a record set. I.e. reading multiple XML files into recordset.

```
Dim xmlDoc,cn,fso,f,xmlDoc2,rs
    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")   
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")  
    Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.3.0")
    Set xmlDoc2 = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.3.0")
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    xmlDoc.async="False"
    xmlDoc2.async="False"
    xmlDoc2.setProperty "SelectionLanguage","XPath"

    ' Create a root element in the new merged xml
    Set objRoot = xmlDoc.createElement("OutDelData")  
    xmlDoc.appendChild objRoot  

    ' Loop all xmls in a folder and extract all OutDelData/OutDeliveries 
     'change the xpath to //* to clone it all
     For Each f In 
     fso.GetFolder("C:\inetpub\wwwroot\HandheldWebService\data\OutDel\ToDeliver").Files
 If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(f))="xml" Then
    xmlDoc2.load f.Path     
        For Each node In xmlDoc2.selectNodes("//OutDelData/OutDeliveries/*")
            Set newnode = node.cloneNode(True)
            xmlDoc.documentElement.appendChild newnode
        Next

End If
    Next

    ' Create new xml header
    Set objIntro = xmlDoc.createProcessingInstruction ("xml","version='1.0'")  
    xmlDoc.insertBefore objIntro,xmlDoc.childNodes(0) 

    ' save the nw merged file
    xmlDoc.save "C:\temp\XML\temp.xml"

    ' Open connection and make use of the data in a data set
    cn.Open "Provider=MSDAOSP;Data Source=MSXML2.DSOControl.3.0"
    rs.Open "C:\temp\XML\temp.xml",cn,3,3
    Debug.WriteLine rs.GetString
    rs.Close
```